# How to delete an element of a nested list at a specific level and a specific position of this level

Tags: list-manipulation

```
(*source*)
sourceStruct =
 {{a, {{c1, d}, {e, f}}}, {b, {{c2, h}, {i, k}}}, {m, {{c3, n}, {v,x}}}}
(*target*)
targetStruct = {{a, {{d}, {e, f}}}, {b, {{h}, {i,k}}}, {m, {{n}, {v, x}}}}
(*try 1*)
Apply[Function[x, Delete[x, 1]], Level[sourceStruct, {2}], {1}]
(*result 1*)
{a, {d}, b, {h}, m, {n}}
(*try 2*)
Map[Function[x, Delete[x, 1]], sourceStruct, {3}]
(*result 2*)
{{a, {{d}, {f}}}, {b, {{h}, {k}}}, {m, {{n}, {x}}}}
```

Comment: Some prose to explain what you intend is usually useful and will help you getting better answers by making answering easier than just having to parse some code and deducing the intentions thereof.

Answer (score 11):

## Methods that require evaluation

You might use `MapAt` along with a function (`kill`) that will be removed when an expression evalutes:

```
_kill := Sequence[]

MapAt[kill, sourceStruct, {All, 2, 1, 1}]
```

> ```
> {{a, {{d}, {e, f}}}, {b, {{h}, {i, k}}}, {m, {{n}, {v, x}}}}
> ```

This is particularly flexible because you can use multiple specifications, and it supports `All` and `Span`.

Similarly you could make an assignment with `Part` but the expression *must* evaluate before the `Sequence[]` expressions are removed:

```
sS2 = sourceStruct;                (* make a copy, else this will modify in-place*)
sS2[[All, 2, 1, 1]] = Sequence[];  (* Sequence[] still in memory *)

sS2
```

> ```
> {{a, {{d}, {e, f}}}, {b, {{h}, {i, k}}}, {m, {{n}, {v, x}}}}
> ```

A terse option is `Delete` and `Map`:

```
Delete[#, {2, 1, 1}] & /@ sourceStruct
```

> ```
> {{a, {{d}, {e, f}}}, {b, {{h}, {i, k}}}, {m, {{n}, {v, x}}}}
> ```

Perhaps closer to your intention, as it includes a *levelspec*, is `Replace`:

```
Replace[sourceStruct, {{_, a_}, b_} :> {{a}, b}, {2}]
```

> ```
> {{a, {{d}, {e, f}}}, {b, {{h}, {i, k}}}, {m, {{n}, {v, x}}}}
> ```

## A method that does not require evaluation

If evaluation is not possible then I recommend [`Delete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Delete.html) alone which will require creating a list of positions:

```
pos = Array[{#, 2, 1, 1} &, Length@sourceStruct]

Delete[sourceStruct, pos]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {3, 2, 1, 1}}
>
> {{a, {{d}, {e, f}}}, {b, {{h}, {i, k}}}, {m, {{n}, {v, x}}}}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Not a general solution but consider the following approach if result2 is your objective:

```
 sourceStruct = {{a, {{c1, d}, {e, f}}}, {b, {{c2, h}, {i,k}}}, {m, {{c3, n}, {v, x}}}}

positions=Flatten[Map[Position[sourceStruct, #] &,{c1, e, c2, i, c3, v}], 1]
Delete[sourceStruct, positions]

{{a, {{d}, {f}}}, {b, {{h}, {k}}}, {m, {{n}, {x}}}}
```

A more general solution for result2, consider a variation of previous answers:

```
positions=Flatten[Table[{i,2,j,1},{i,1,Length[sourceStruct]},{j,1,Length[sourceStruct]-1}],1]   
Delete[sourceStruct, positions]

{{a, {{d}, {f}}}, {b, {{h}, {k}}}, {m, {{n}, {x}}}}
```

And, by extension, adding to the elegant solution by Wizard:

```
  _kill := Sequence[]
sourceStruct = {{a, {{c1, d}, {e, f}}}, {b, {{c2, h}, {i, k}}}, {m, {{c3, n}, {v, x}}}};
result2 = MapAt[kill, sourceStruct, {All, 2, All, 1}]

{{a, {{d}, {f}}}, {b, {{h}, {k}}}, {m, {{n}, {x}}}}
```