# Delete all data points of a specific row if any one column has a string or "NA"

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

I have

```
   mydata= {{{2017, 1, 1}, 116.461, 61.7762, 65.4011},
           {{2017, 1, 8}, 117.577, 61.6386, "NA"},
          {{2017, 1, 15}, 118.525, 61.6779, 45.62},
          {{2017, 1, 22}, 120.451, "NA", "NA"},
          {{2017, 1, 29}, 127.494, 62.602, 85.25},
          {{2017, 1, 29}, "NA", 62.602, 88.25}};
```

I am looking for different ways to delete all data points of all rows that have at least one "NA". My result should be as fallow:

```
myresult = {{{2017, 1, 1}, 116.461, 61.7762, 65.4011},
            {{2017, 1, 15}, 118.525, 61.6779, 45.62},
            {{2017, 1, 29},127.494, 62.602, 85.25}};
```

Although this example has just a few rows and a few columns, my actual data has many more rows and columns. [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35101/how-to-delete-all-rows-in-datafile-that-contain-a-string) is related question but answer was not much helpful for me. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862178/remove-rows-with-nas-missing-values-in-data-frame) is related question from stackoverflow.com. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: See `Select` and `FreeQ`. If you need better performance the three argument form of `FeeQ` may help.

Comment: another option `Pick[mydata,Not[MemberQ[#,"NA"]]&/@mydata]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In decreasing order of brevity:

```
mydata // Select[FreeQ["NA"]]

Cases[mydata, Except[{___, "NA", ___}]]

Delete[mydata, {#} & @@@ Position[mydata, "NA"]]
```

Slightly more involved to set up, but convenient afterward:

```
{___, kill[], ___} ^:= Sequence[]

mydata /. "NA" -> kill[]
```

Related:

- [How to delete an element of a nested list at a specific level and a specific position of this level](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65027/121)

Comment: @ Mr. Wizard, thank your for your answer. All these answers are very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

```
Select[mydata, ! MemberQ[#, "NA"] &]
```

Comment: @ David, thank you for your time and answer. I think it addresses my concern.

Answer (score 4):

```
Cases[mydata, {_, __?NumericQ}]
```

Or

```
DeleteCases[mydata, {___, _String, ___}]
```

Or

```
Replace[mydata, {___, _String, ___} :> Sequence[], {1}]
```

> {{{2017, 1, 1}, 116.461, 61.7762, 65.4011}, {{2017, 1, 15}, 118.525, 
>     61.6779, 45.62}, {{2017, 1, 29}, 127.494, 62.602, 85.25}}

Comment: @ eldo, thank you for your time and answer. I have tried doing this but I was not sure whether it would be general enough to handle any number of columns. I think it can handle any number of columns.

Answer (score 3):

If you're dataset used `Missing["NA"]` you could just use [`DeleteMissing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteMissing). Instead, I will replace "NA" with `Missing["NA"]` and then use [`DeleteMissing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteMissing):

```
DeleteMissing[
    Replace[mydata, "NA"->Missing["NA"], {2}],
    1,
    Infinity
]
```

> {{{2017, 1, 1}, 116.461, 61.7762, 65.4011}, {{2017, 1, 15}, 118.525, 61.6779, 
>     45.62}, {{2017, 1, 29}, 127.494, 62.602, 85.25}}

Comment: @ Carl, thank you for your time and answer. I think it addresses my concern.

Answer (score 3):

```
mydata /. {___, _String, ___} :> Nothing
```

Comment: @ jiaoeyushushu, thank you for your time and answer.